# How can I use parent's callback in children component?

Tags: react-native, callback, use-state

Sorry. I'm new to react native and react.
And I just encountered `setCount is not a function. (In 'setCount(1)','setCount' is undefined)` error.
How can I use `setCount` Method in AComponent?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
} from 'react-native';


const AComponent = ({count, callback}) => {
  callback(1);
  return <Text>{count}</Text>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <AComponent count={count} callback={setCount} />;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are renaming your function to callback.

So in your component you need to use callback instead of setCount, or rename your props callback to setCount (preferable):

```
return <AComponent count={count} setCount={setCount} />
```

Each key={value} defined when you use your component, can be accessed with the key in the component.

I suggest you to have a deep read of the following article: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I'm glad! If the answer solved the error, please accept it. Regards